# What are the different ways to unwrap a model in blender with multiple parts?

Tags: uv

I'm new to Blender and new to unwrapping in Blender. I know there is a simple way to create seams around each part and then unwrap them.

I have made complex models and I feel like this is the quick and easy way and not a proper way to unwrap.

Is there a method to unwrap each individual piece of a model so you can make sure it turns out correctly

Comment: Ctrl + E > Mark Seams while in edge select mode. U can also use U > Smart UV Unwrap.

Comment: IMHO, what you are asking is dependent of the kind of model you have made (image rendering, game, other...). It can also depend of the textures you want to use (already made textures, baking, ...). You should add some information about all that (eventually some screen shots).

Comment: I would b making my own textures from scratch for a video game. I would make textures on gimpshop. And so in 3rd max unwrapped each part of my model individually cuz I tv turned out better then marking all the seems n unwrapping cuz it didn't turn our correctly . N i want to do that with blender. But idk the interface that well.ik  How to put seems down n Mark them. But is their a way besides marking all the seems n unwrapping ? Is their another way then that in blender